# En quoi diffèrent « à dormir debout » et « ne pas tenir debout » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, synonymes

On a la locution usuelle *à dormir [debout](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/debout)* (*invraisemblable*, [Larousse en ligne](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dormir/26496/locution?q=dormir%20debout#154778) ; *qui n'a aucun sens, qui ne peut pas être vrai*, [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_dormir_debout))  et au TLFi on trouve ceci :

> [II A 2 a) : II Debout est en relation avec une personne / A En
>   fonction d'épithète, d'appos., ou d'attribut / 2 Par ext. / a Qui est
>   hors du lit, levé ou non couché. / Locutions ] :
>
> *(Un conte, une histoire, des propos, etc.) à dormir debout*. Qui manque de vraisemblance, de sérieux, de logique ou d'intérêt (cf.
>   supra I A 2). **Quasi-synonyme** *qui ne tient pas debout*. *Des raisonnements philosophiques, vagues, rebattus, à dormir debout* (Stendhal, *Racine et Shakspeare*, 1823, p. 45). *L'histoire n'est qu'une histoire à dormir debout* (Renard, *Journal*, 1901, p. 665).
>
> [I A 2 : I Debout est en relation avec un inanimé / A Usuel / 2. Au
>   fig. [Inanimé abstr.] / Locutions verbales ]
>
> [...]
>   *Tenir debout.* Être acceptable, cohérent, sérieux. *J'avais beau compter sur mes doigts, pas un de ces vers ne semblait tenir debout*
>   (Green, *Journal*, 1933, p. 135). Le plus souvent sous la forme
>   négative. *Ne pas tenir debout*. Manquer de vraisemblance, de logique,
>   de sérieux ou de réalisme. *Ton histoire ne tient pas debout* (Achard,
>   *J. de la Lune*, 1929, III, 3, p. 27). *Ça ne tenait pas debout comme accusation* (Céline, *Voyage*, 1932, p. 575).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, extraits de « debout » 
>   avec indications entre crochets ]

- Peut-on préciser en quoi diffèrent *à dormir debout* et *ne pas tenir
  debout* et la nuance en est-elle davantage une de sens, de degré,
  syntaxique, conceptuelle ou autrement ; est-ce une question de cooccurrences particulières ou d'un emploi plus restreint avec une des locutions ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tout d'abord, il faut signaler que l'expression "à dormir debout" a toujours le même sens, alors que l'utilisation de "ne pas tenir debout" peut varier selon le contexte.

"Dormir debout" frôle l'impossible (du moins pour un être humain, cfr [ici](https://www.reponse-conso.fr/pratique/sante-bien-etre/peut-on-dormir-debout-a109251)), donc une histoire à dormir debout est une histoire qui semble loufoque, exagérée, incroyable dans son ensemble... Autrement dit, elle n'a ni queue ni tête. En général, ce sont des histoires assez complexes.

"Ne pas tenir debout" fait référence à un effondrement prochain. Par exemple:

> Je suis mort de fatigue; je ne tiens plus debout; il faut que j'aille
>   dormir sinon je vais m'effondrer.

Dans le contexte où l'on signale l'invraisemblance, une histoire qui ne tient pas debout peut sembler vraisemblable à première vue, mais un élément de l'histoire la rend invraisemblable (comme si l'on enlevait une carte à la base d'un château de cartes, ce qui provoquerait l'effondrement de tout l'édifice). Par exemple:

> Ton histoire ne tient pas debout. Comment peux-tu avoir regardé la
>   télévision pendant une heure alors qu'il y avait une panne de courant
>   dans tout le quartier?

Pour conclure, l'histoire à dormir debout apparaît comme invraisemblable dans son ensemble alors que l'histoire qui ne tient pas debout ne pèche que par l'un ou l'autre détail. J'ajouterais qu'une histoire à dormir debout est invraisemblable mais parfois vraie, alors qu'une histoire qui ne tient pas debout est plutôt vraisemblable à première vue mais fausse en réalité.

Comment: Dormir debout est physiologiquement tout à fait possible  pour un être humain, seulement ça relève d'un état pathologique.

Comment: Mreci pour la remarque, j'ai ajouté un lien. Notez que j'avais écrit "frôle" au lieu de "est". Par ailleurs, si vous faites allusion au somnambulisme, celui-ci n'advient que durant la phase de sommeil lent. Durant le sommeil paradoxal il ne semble pas possible de dormir debout.